# Passing data with "putExtra" in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, model, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to pass some details data from my model to another activity using class recyclerview adapter.

**Adapters's code:**

```
public class Tab1RecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Tab1RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Tab1BookModel> bookList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public Tab1RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Tab1BookModel> bookList) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.bookList = bookList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_list_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Tab1BookModel book = bookList.get(position);
    holder.setData(book, position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bookList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView downloadIcon;
    private TextView bookTitle, bookAuthor;
    private View container;
    private int position;
    private Tab1BookModel book;

    MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        bookTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        bookAuthor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        downloadIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download_icon);
        //            downloadIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        container = view.findViewById(R.id.container_book_list_item);
        container.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void setData(Tab1BookModel book, int position) {
        this.bookTitle.setText(book.getTab1BookTitle());
        this.bookAuthor.setText(book.getTab1BookAuthor());
        this.position = position;
        this.book = book;
    }
```

**OnClick method:**

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, BookReaderActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("content", bookList.get(position).getTab1BookContent());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Model's code:**

```
public class Tab1BookModel {

private int bookTitle;
private int bookAuthor;
private int bookContent;

public int getTab1BookTitle() {
    return bookTitle;
}

public void setBookTitle(int bookTitle) {
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
}

public int getTab1BookAuthor() {
    return bookAuthor;
}

public void setBookAuthor(int bookAuthor) {
    this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
}

public int getTab1BookContent() {
    return bookContent;
}

public void setBookContent(int bookContent) {
    this.bookContent = bookContent;
}

public static List<Tab1BookModel> getObjectList() {

    List<Tab1BookModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] title = getTitle();
    int[] author = getAuthor();
    int[] content = getContent();

    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        Tab1BookModel books = new Tab1BookModel();
        books.setBookTitle(title[i]);
        books.setBookAuthor(author[i]);
        books.setBookContent(content[i]);
        dataList.add(books);
    }
    return dataList;
}

private static int[] getTitle() {
    int[] title = {
            R.string.title_1, R.string.title_2, R.stringtitle_3,
            R.string.title_4, R.string.title_5, R.string.title_6,
            R.string.title_7, R.string.title_8, R.string.title_9
    };
    return title;
}

private static int[] getAuthor() {
    int[] author = {
            R.string.author_1, R.string.author_2, R.string.author_3,
            R.string.author_4, R.string.author_5, R.string.author_6,
            R.string.author_7, R.string.author_8, R.string.author_9
    };
    return author;
}
```

**List of the data, from which I need to pass one item to another activity:**

```
private static int[] getContent() {
    int[] content = {
            R.string.book_1, R.string.book_2, R.string.book_3,
            R.string.book_4, R.string.book_5, R.string.book_6,
            R.string.book_7, R.string.book_8, R.string.book_9
    };
    return content;
}

}
```

**Activity, in which I want to pass some data:**

```
public class BookReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView bookContent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_reader);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    bookContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book_content);

    bookContent.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("content"));
}

}
```

Comment: How is your BookReaderActivity.class looks like? Maybe the data is passed, but that class doesn't receive it.

Comment: I have added a description for BookReaderActivity.class

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pass the String resource id, you need to get the String first with the resource id, like this:

```
String stringBookContent = getResources().getString(getIntent().getIntExtra("content", 0));
bookContent.setText(stringBookContent);
```

Add it on the BookReaderActivity class.

Comment: It works perfectly, **_thanks_** a lot! But the problem wasn't actualy in getting String id first. You can also code like this 'bookContent.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("content", 0));' and it will work as perfect as you sollution works. But anyway, thanks, I had such a buthert for this problem. From Russia with love!

Comment: Haha, ok, I see. I didn't really test it, actually, it is just the safest way to implement. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to log inside your OnClick method to confirm that it is called and then in your Activity you can return data as

```
getIntent.getIntExtra("content");
```

Comment: Android Studio writes, that String cannot use "getIntExtra"